# How to swap two value in generic way?

Tags: c++, templates, swap

Consider this code.

```
template<typename E>
void swap(E &_Left, E &_Right){
    E tmp = _Left;
    _Left = _Right;
    _Right = tmp;
}

template<typename E>
void bubble_sort(E begin, E end){
    for(E i = begin; i != end - 1; ++i){
        for(E j = end - 1; j != i; --j){
            if(*j < *(j-1)){
                 swap(*j, *(j - 1)); // here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know how `swap` function implements. But if I don't want to use a function to swap the value, how to specify the type of temporary variable when swapping the values. `template` is also wanted.

Comment: What's wrong with std::swap?

Comment: btw. your bubble sort can be optimized

Comment: No wrong with `std::swap`, I just want to know how to specify the type of temporary variable as said above.@PhilM

Comment: Do you mean when check whether the original sequence has been sorted in the first loop?@deW1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to specify the type of temporary variable when swapping the values

If you want to specify the type explicitly, you can use [std::iterator_traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits):

```
typename std::iterator_traits<E>::value_type tmp = ...;
```

Since C++11, you can use `auto` directly, like

```
auto tmp = ...;
```

---

BTW: Don't use names beginning with an underscore followed immediately by an uppercase letter; they're always reserved to the implementation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and advice~

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use something like

```
auto &temp = *(j-1);
*(j-1) = *i;
*i = temp;
```